# selenium how to get the content of href within some targeted class

Tags: python, html, css, xpath, selenium

I am trying to retrieve the data from the webpage has the html in below

```
       <div class="someclass">
       <p class="name"><a href="#/word/1/">helloworld</a></p>
       </div>
```

My goal is to parse "#/word/1/"
What I did is

```
        target = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('someclass')
        print target
        print target.text
        print target.get_attribute("css=a@href")
        print target.tag_name
```

but the output are

```
 <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x10bf16210>
 helloworld
 None
 div
```

I tried so many ways , it seems there is no way i can get the content of 'a href' within the targeted class.

I really dont want to do is get the source code of the page, and then do a string searching, that seems dumb....

anyway to get that?

Comment: Why are you not getting the actual anchor element? `anchorElement = target.find_element_by_tag_name('a')` ...you can then do.... `print anchorElement.get_attribute("href")`....right....?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

As far as I am aware you can get the href by searching through the child elements

```
div = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('someclass')
div.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')
```

Comment: Without you, I would never have come up with that myself. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 10):

This should do it for you:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.someclass a').get_attribute('href')
```

Answer (score 1):

if you search for special tag use from find_element_by_id or **classname** or **xpath**
and then use **get_attribute('href')**

in this example print all attribute for a tags

```
   ids = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@href]')
   for id in ids:
        print(id.get_attribute('href'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
div = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'abcxyz')
content = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,'Click_Me').get_attribute('href')
print(content)
```

Iam using selenium==4.7.2