# Python and selenium - get all links from webpage

Tags: python, selenium, hyperlink

I have a script that download all .csv files from a site. It is working ok but I need also to get a list with the urls to .csv files.
The part of code for downloading looks like:

```
# Download files according to Xpath in table
def downloadfiles(Xpath):
    global browser
    time.sleep(10);
    # Click csv img
    try:
        browser.find_element_by_xpath(Xpath).click()
        global downloadcount
        downloadcount = downloadcount + 1
        return
    # Element not found
    except NoSuchElementException as e:
        print("Error enxontró csv")
    return
```

Here I think i need to do something: `browser.find_element_by_xpath(Xpath).click()`
instead of click I want to get the link.
The code is made in python 3.6 and selenium.
Xpath is `"//*[@id=\"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ListViewNodos_ctrl0_ListViewArchivosSIN_ctrl0_linkCSV\"]"`

How can I get the links list to .csv files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [selenium how to get the content of href within some targeted class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664253/selenium-how-to-get-the-content-of-href-within-some-targeted-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the link using `get_attribute("href")`
use below line of code

```
link = browser.find_element_by_xpath(Xpath).get_attribute("href")
print link
```