# Web scraping with BeautifulSoup won't work

Tags: javascript, python, class, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Ultimately, I'm trying to open all articles of a news website and then make a top 10 of the words used in all the articles. To do this, I first wanted to see how many articles there are so I could iterate over them at some point, haven't really figured out how I want to do everything yet.

To do this, I wanted to use BeautifulSoup4. I think the class I'm trying to get is Javascript as I'm not getting anything back. 
This is my code:

```
url = "http://ad.nl"
ad = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(ad.text.lower(), "xml")
titels = soup.findAll("article")

print(titels)
for titel in titels:
    print(titel)
```

The article name is sometimes an h2 or an h3. It always has one and the same class, but I can't get anything through that class. It has some parents but it uses the same name but with the extension -wrapper for example. I don't even know how to use a parent to get what I want but I think that those classes are Javascript as well. There's also an href which I'm interested in. But once again, that is probably also Javascript as it returns nothing.

Does anyone know how I could use anything (preferably the href, but the article name would be ok as well) by using BeautifulSoup?

Comment: if you open your url in a browser, you can *View Source*.  **IF** what you want is there, then it comes from the server, not added via JS, so Beautifulsoup would work.  If it does come from the server, I would then use an appropriate CSS selector, which you can use use via `$("<selector>")` in the browser's dev tools console.  Once that works, in-browser, `soup.select("<selector>")` can take over.  Far as I can tell, you get as much functionality via CSS selectors in **BeautifulSoup** as with its custom `find`.  The difference is that you can get help from front-end folk with CSS.

Comment: One problem I'm running into is when opening the page, you get that Accept Cookie page first. You can't proceed to get the articles without getting past that page.

Comment: @Sri  nice!  never thought of GDPR cookies as a scraping blocker, but then again I know didly about scraping, my viewpoint is limited to how to grab data out of webpages for unit testing.  does anyone know if requests can be sweet-talked into GDPR cookie acceptance (it probably can't, but why not ask) ?  or do you have to go straight to selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sri mentioned in the comments, when you open up that url, you have a page show up where you have to accept the cookies first, which requires interaction.
When you need interaction, consider using something like selenium (https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).

Here's something that should get you started.

(Edit: you'll need to run `pip install selenium` before running this code below)

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://ad.nl'

# launch firefox with your url above
# note that you could change this to some other webdriver (e.g. Chrome)
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

# click the "accept cookies" button
btn = driver.find_element_by_name('action')
btn.click()

# grab the html. It'll wait here until the page is finished loading
html = driver.page_source

# parse the html soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.lower(), "html.parser")
articles = soup.findAll("article")

for article in articles:
    # check for article titles in both h2 and h3 elems
    h2_titles = article.findAll('h2', {'class': 'ankeiler__title'})
    h3_titles = article.findAll('h3', {'class': 'ankeiler__title'})
    for t in h2_titles:
        # first I was doing print(t.text), but some of them had leading
        # newlines and things like '22:30', which I assume was the hour of the day
        text = ''.join(t.findAll(text=True, recursive=False)).lstrip()
        print(text)
    for t in h3_titles:
        text = ''.join(t.findAll(text=True, recursive=False)).lstrip()
        print(text)

# close the browser
driver.close()
```

This may or may not be exactly what you have in mind, but this is just an example of how to use selenium and beautiful soup. Feel free to copy/use/modify this as you see fit.
And if you're wondering about what selectors to use, read the comment by @JL Peyret.

Comment: This works indeed, awesome! I thought it was possible to also do: soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.lower(), "html.parser") instead of soup = BeautifulSoup(html.lower(), "html.parser") but this doesn't work. Could you explain me why that's the case? Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: `driver` is an object. Try running `print(driver)` and/or `print(type(driver))`. `html`, on the other hand, is just a `str`.

Comment: Thank you again. At this moment, I'm trying to get all the hrefs that go an article as I want to somehow click all of them at a later moment. I thought I could just change your code a bit but it doesn't seem to work. I changed this:     `h2_titles = article.findAll('h2', {'class': 'ankeiler__title'})` 
to:     `links = article.findAll('a', {'class': 'ankeiler__link'})`
and then I wanted to `print(links`) but I think it gives me the entire html of the page. Do you know what I should do to only get the links or do you maybe know a different way for me to click those links one after another?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664253/selenium-how-to-get-the-content-of-href-within-some-targeted-class.

Comment: It's working to some extent now. It gives me the first href, but as soon as I try to iterate, it keeps giving me the first href as many times as I iterate. Im sorry for asking that much but do you maybe know how to iterate to the next href instead of staying stuck in the first, I couldn't figure it out right now. I tried several pieces of code but this is what I've got right now: 
`for i in articles:

    article = driver.find_element_by_class_name('ankeiler')

    hrefs = article.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')

    print(hrefs)

driver.quit()`

Comment: I think this probably belongs in a new question. Plus it's a pain to do in the comments lol

Comment: Haha you're right. I just posted the question. I appreciate your time and answers a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't want to use selenium. This works for me. I've tried on 2 PCs with different internet connection. Can you try?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

cookies={"pwv":"2",
"pws":"functional|analytics|content_recommendation|targeted_advertising|social_media"}

page=requests.get("https://www.ad.nl/",cookies=cookies)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

articles = soup.findAll("article")
```

Then follow kimbo's code to extract h2/h3.

Comment: Yes it works for me as well, it gets me all some different html stuff from the articles. Could you please explain further what you did with the cookies? I don't really understand what's going on there, thanks!

Comment: I like this approach @inxp! +1

Comment: The website sets these cookies on successful GPDR acceptance and some other Adblock/tracking related checks. We are just setting these cookies by ourselves and sending as part of `get` request.