# How to get link from body of email - Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

okay so i've got another problem.
The link from the picture below is what I am trying to click on. Sometimes it would work and sometimes it will not.
Here's what was done :

`VALUE = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("https://www.example.to/verify-account?code").get_attribute('value') print(VALUE)`

and here's the results : `None`

Somehow it isn't getting the result eventhough I had set it to sleep for 4 seconds to compensate for the loading time.
[image: verification email]

Comment: i got it working from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664253/selenium-how-to-get-the-content-of-href-within-some-targeted-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using explicit wait and using `getText()` instead of `getAttribute()`:

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "https://www.example.to/verify-account?code"))).getText()
```

the driver will wait until your element ready to click base on your input time. In this case, I set it 15 seconds. May be 4 seconds is not enough for the DOM to load.

Comment: hi, i've tried that but got : ' raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: '