# How to click a link by text with No Text in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a Wine data from vivino.com and using selenium to automate it and scrape as many data as possible. My code looks like this:

```
import time 
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe')

browser.get('https://www.vivino.com/explore?e=eJwFwbEOQDAUBdC_uaNoMN7NZhQLEXmqmiZaUk3x987xkVXRwLtAVcLLy7qE_tiN0Bz6FhcV7M4s0ZkkB86VUZIL9l4kmyjW4ORmbo0nTTPVDxlkGvg%3D&cart_item_source=nav-explore') # Vivino Website with 5 wines for now (simple example). Plan to scrape around 10,000 wines 

lenOfPage = browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")

match=False
while(match==False):
    lastCount = lenOfPage
    time.sleep(7)
    lenOfPage = browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
    if lastCount==lenOfPage:
        match=True
```

That opens a website with 5 wines and scrolls down. Now I want to click to hyperlink of the wine one by one to scrape information about its price, wine grapes sort, etc. So, basically my script will try scroll down which allows to have as many wines displayed on the page and then click to a first hyperlink, get additional information and go back. Then, the process will repeat. I don't think that's an efficient strategy but that's what I came up so far.

The problem I have is with hyperlink in the vivino website. There is no text near the href link which allows me to use **find_element_by_link_text** function:

```
<a class="anchor__anchor--2QZvA" href="/weingut-r-a-pfaffl-austrian-cherry-zweigelt/w/1261542?year=2018&amp;price_id=23409078&amp;cart_item_source=direct-explore" target="_blank">
```

Could you please suggest the way how click for a wine with Selenium that has not text after the hyperlink? I haven't found proper answer during my web search. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're doing way more work than you have to - with Selenium I mean. When visiting the page, I logged my network traffic with Google Chrome's dev tools, and I saw that my browser made an HTTP GET request to a REST API, the response of which is JSON and contains all the wine/price information you could ever want. So, you don't need to do any scraping. Just imitate that GET request with the desired query-string parameters and the correct headers. It seems the REST API just cares about the `user-agent` header, which is trivial.

---

1. First, visit the [URL](https://www.vivino.com/explore?e=eJwFwTsKgDAQBcDbvFIMIlavMxcQrERkjTEEjMoa_NzemaSsihop7myQ5GVVwn1sLRxt3-GkQVh5i0afZcMxUyXHPVyT3F4leBxc_OXw5GGk-QEEAxqx&cart_item_source=nav-explore)
   in Google Chrome.
2. Press the `F12` key to open the Google Chrome dev tools menu.
   Click on the `Network` tab.
3. Click on the round Record button. It should turn red, and it will
   start logging all network traffic in the log below. Click on the
   Filter button next to it, and then click on `XHR`. This will only
   show XHR (XmlHttpRequest) requests in the log. We are interested in
   these requests specifically, because it is via XHR that requests to
   APIs are typically made. Here's what it should look like now:

[image]

4. With the Chrome dev tools menu still open, right-click (not
   left-click) on the page refresh button to reveal a drop-down menu.
   Then, click on `Empty Cache and Hard Reload`.

[image]

This will empty your browser's cache for this page, and force your
browser to refresh the page. As the page is being refreshed, you
should start to see some entries appearing in the traffic log.

[image]

There should now be some XHR request entries in the log. We don't know which one of these is the one we're actually interested in, so we just look at all of them until we find one that looks like it could be the right one (or, if it contains the information we're looking for, like information for individual wines, etc.). I happen to know that we are interested in the one that starts with `explore?...`, so let's click on that.

5. Once you click on the entry, a panel will open on the right of the
   log. Click on the `Headers` tab.

[image]

This tab contains all the information regarding how this request was made. Under the `General` area, you can see the `Request URL`, which is the URL to the REST API endpoint that we made a request to. This URL might be quite long, because it will also typically contain the query-string parameters (those are the key-value pairs that come after `explore?`, like `country_code=DE` or `currency_code=EUR`. They are separated by `&`). The query-string parameters are important, because they contain information about certain filters that we want to apply to our query. In my code example, I've removed them from the REST API endpoint URL, and instead moved them into the `params` dictionary. This step isn't required - you could also just leave them in the URL, but I find that it is easier to read and modify this way. The query-string parameters are also important because, sometimes, certains APIs will expect certain parameters to be present in the request, or they will expect them to have certain values - in other words, some APIs are very picky about their query-string parameters, and if you remove them or tamper with them in a way that the API doesn't expect, the API will say that your request isn't formulated correctly.

In the `General` area, you can also see `Request Method`, which in our case is `GET`. This tells us, that our browser made an HTTP GET request. Not all API endpoints work the same, some want HTTP POST, etc.

`Status Code` tells us what status code the server sent back. `200` means everything went OK. You can learn more about [HTTP status codes here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

Let's take a look at the `Response Headers` area. This area contains all the response headers that the server sent back after the request was made. These can be useful for a browser for things like setting cookies or knowing how to interpret the data the server has sent back.

The `Request Headers` area contains all the headers that your browser sent to the server when it made the request. Usually, it's a good idea to copy all of these key-value pairs and turn them into a Python dictionary `headers`, because that way you can be sure that your Python script will make the exact same request that your browser made. However, usually, I like to trim this down as much as I can. I know that many APIs desperately care about the `user-agent` field, so usually I'll keep that one, but sometimes they also care about the `referer`. As you work with different APIs, you'll have to just kind of figure out which request headers the API cares about through trial-and-error. This API happens to only care about the `user-agent`.

The last area `Query String Parameters` is just a cute way of showing the query-string parameters from the `Request URL` in a human-friendly list of key-value pairs. Sometimes it's helpful to copy them from here, rather than from the URL.

6. Now, click on the `Preview` tab, next to the `Headers` tab.

[image]

The `Preview` tab contains a pretty-printed preview of the actual data that was sent back as a result of the browser's request. In our case, this contains the JSON data sent back by the server. You can click on the little gray triangles to expand or collapse certain parts of the JSON structure, to reveal different data.

[image]

Looking at this, I can tell that the JSON response is one big dictionary, which has a key `explore_vintage`, whose value is another dictionary, which has a key `records` whose value is a list of dictionaries, where each dictionary in this list represents one wine object. Expanding the first record (the 0th one) reveals all information regarding the first wine in the list. You can explore these structures as much as you like to see what kinds of information are available to you.

[image]

---

```
def main():

    import requests

    url = "https://www.vivino.com/api/explore/explore"

    params = {
        "country_code": "DE",
        "currency_code": "EUR",
        "grape_filter": "varietal",
        "min_rating": "3.5",
        "order_by": "ratings_average",
        "order": "desc",
        "page": "1",
        "price_range_max": "30",
        "price_range_min": "7",
        "wine_type_ids[]": "1"
    }

    headers = {
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0"
    }

    response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
    response.raise_for_status()

    records = response.json()["explore_vintage"]["records"]

    for record in records:
        name = record["vintage"]["name"]
        price = record["price"]["amount"]
        currency = record["price"]["currency"]["code"]
        print(f"\"{name}\" - Price: {price} {currency}")

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
"Varvaglione Cosimo Varvaglione Collezione Privata Primitivo di Manduria 2015" - Price: 21.9 EUR
"Masseria Borgo dei Trulli Mirea Primitivo di Manduria 2019" - Price: 19.9 EUR
"Vigneti del Salento Vigne Vecchie Primitivo di Manduria 2016" - Price: 22.95 EUR
"Vigneti del Salento Vigne Vecchie Leggenda Primitivo di Manduria 2016" - Price: 17.87 EUR
"Varvaglione Papale Linea Oro Primitivo di Manduria 2016" - Price: 18.85 EUR
"Caballo Loco Grand Cru Apalta 2014" - Price: 27.9 EUR
"Luccarelli Il Bacca Old Vine Primitivo di Manduria 2016" - Price: 20.9 EUR
"Mottura Stilio Primitivo di Manduria 2018" - Price: 12.89 EUR
"Caballo Loco Grand Cru Maipo 2015" - Price: 24.81 EUR
"Lorusso Michele Solone Primitivo 2017" - Price: 21.39 EUR
"Château Purcari Negru de Purcari 2017" - Price: 29.8 EUR
"San Marzano 60 Sessantanni Limited Edition Old Vines Primitivo di Manduria 2016" - Price: 22.85 EUR
"San Marzano 60 Sessantanni Old Vines Primitivo di Manduria 2016" - Price: 20.9 EUR
"San Marzano 60 Sessantanni Old Vines Primitivo di Manduria 2017" - Price: 17.775 EUR
"Lenotti Amarone della Valpolicella Classico 2015" - Price: 27.95 EUR
"Zeni Cruino Rosso Veronese 2015" - Price: 22.9 EUR
"Masseria Pietrosa Palmenti Primitivo di Manduria Vigne Vecchie 2016" - Price: 25 EUR
"Ravazzi Prezioso 2016" - Price: 29.95 EUR
"Nino Negri Sfursat Carlo Negri 2017" - Price: 23.89 EUR
"Quinta do Paral Reserva Tinto 2017" - Price: 29.24 EUR
"Wildekrans Barrel Select Reserve Pinotage 2016" - Price: 29.9 EUR
"Caballo Loco Grand Cru Limarí 2016" - Price: 27.9 EUR
"San Marzano F Negroamaro 2018" - Price: 16.9 EUR
"Atlan & Artisan 8 Vents Mallorca 2018" - Price: 19 EUR
"Schneider Rooi Olifant Red 2017" - Price: 19.5 EUR
>>>
```

It just seems to grab twenty-five records/wines per page, but changing the `page` key-value pair in the `params` query-string parameter dictionary will yield the records from whatever page you desire. I'm currently located in Germany, that's why my `country_code` and `currency_code` are `"DE"` and `"EUR"`, but you should be able to change those to suit your needs.

---

EDIT - here are some more key-value pairs you may be interested in, though I would recommend you get familiar with how your browser's dev tools work so that you can discover these fields in the JSON yourself:

```
record["vintage"]["year"]
record["vintage"]["wine"]["region"]["name"]
record["vintage"]["wine"]["region"]["country"]["name"]
record["vintage"]["wine"]["taste"]["structure"]["acidity"]
record["vintage"]["wine"]["taste"]["structure"]["intensity"]
record["vintage"]["wine"]["taste"]["structure"]["sweetness"]
record["vintage"]["wine"]["taste"]["structure"]["tannin"]
record["vintage"]["wine"]["style"]["grapes"][0]["name"] # 0th grape information
record["vintage"]["wine"]["winery"]["name"]
```

The JSON unfortunately doesn't contain the alcohol content. This information is hardcoded in the HTML of a given wine's summary page. You would have to make a request to each wine summary page and pull the alcohol content value out of the page, maybe with a regex.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! I tried to access vivino api from their website, but could not find it. If I would like to scrape other wine (or any othere alcohol database) should I try the following: url = www.website.com/api/explore/explore or the api path is different for each case?   Also, if there is a way to automate page key-value pair as I want to scrape 10,000 wine data and I don't think that doing it by hand will be fun :) Finally, is there is a way to access an additional data: For example an alcohol content or the types of grapes used in wine production? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Beginn_noo You're welcome. The API URL `.../api/explore/explore` will not be the same for every REST API you come across. The developers of a REST API are free to name the API endpoints however they like - also, not every website uses a REST API to populate the front-end, so you got lucky this time :). For your second question, it's very easy to automate this. It would basically be a for-loop. Each iteration of the loop, you change the `page` parameter in `params`, and you make another request to the API to get the records for that page, and collect all records page by page.

Comment: @Beginn_noo For your third question, I'll have to take another look at what the API returns. I will let you know what I find out.

Comment: Great, Cheers! I want to gather as much features as possible that will hopefully increase accuracy of ML predictions further in the project. I will try to play with it myself now

Comment: Sorry for asking question a bit late, but how did you check that browser made a _HTTP GET to Rest API_? I have been looking through tutorials for some time and couldn't find a meaningful tutorial  that explains how to get a json result from public API. Can you share useful resources? I also expect that you filled params _keys_ (country_code, currency_code, etc) from the chrome Dev Tools as well. When I go to _Network _ section of dev tools, I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: @Beginn_noo No problem. I've edited my answer with a mini-guide to get you up to speed. Hope it's useful to you! Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Wow, Thank you a lot for all the writing you have done. It was really useful! Your well written explanation saved me several days of struggles on how this works. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer your question, how to select the `a` tag with selenium to perform the `.click()`:

```
links = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.cleanWineCard__cleanWineCard--tzKxV.cleanWineCard__row--CBPRR > a')
```

Using the `css selector` you can locate the `div` tag where the image of the wine is placed in surrounded by an `a` tag.

Now you could loop the `links` perform the `.click()` and do what ever you wanna do:

```
for a in links:
    a.click()
    # grab information
    # sleep a bit
    #...
```

Comment: Great, Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to So - Just in case, you should give the api a try ;) there are all the information in good structure: 
'0: {group: "oak", stats: {count: 98, score: 13110}}
1: {group: "black_fruit", stats: {count: 88, score: 11221}}
2: {group: "spices", stats: {count: 62, score: 3268}}
3: {group: "non_oak", stats: {count: 58, score: 1243}}
...
structure:
acidity: 1.6542798
calculated_structure_count: 278
fizziness: null
intensity: 4.087247
sweetness: 3.0625458
tannin: 2.21928
user_structure_count: 63`

Answer (score 1):

1-
By beautiful soup you can do the following. I change the code a little but you can still use the beautiful soup part.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time, os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


chromedriver = "C:\\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver" # path to the chromedriver executable
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get('https://www.vivino.com/explore?e=eJwFwbEOQDAUBdC_uaNoMN7NZhQLEXmqmiZaUk3x987xkVXRwLtAVcLLy7qE_tiN0Bz6FhcV7M4s0ZkkB86VUZIL9l4kmyjW4ORmbo0nTTPVDxlkGvg%3D&cart_item_source=nav-explore')

#browser.get('https://www.vivino.com/explore?e=eJwFwbEOQDAUBdC_uaNoMN7NZhQLEXmqmiZaUk3x987xkVXRwLtAVcLLy7qE_tiN0Bz6FhcV7M4s0ZkkB86VUZIL9l4kmyjW4ORmbo0nTTPVDxlkGvg%3D&cart_item_source=nav-explore') # Vivino Website with 5 wines for now (simple example). Plan to scrape around 10,000 wines 

lenOfPage = driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")

list= []

match=False
while(match==False):
    lastCount = lenOfPage
    time.sleep(7)
    lenOfPage = driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
    match=True
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

    for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        print(  a['href'] )
```

and it will list you all the hrefs.

2- For alternative: selenium also supports getting element by XPath. you can inspect the item and copy the XPath and then you can use it. Please check the guide below. It will help.
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

for example the following works. I got this working code from at link https://stackoverflow.com/a/63828196/3756587. all credit goes to user mamal : https://stackoverflow.com/users/4941102/mamal

```
    links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@href]')
    for i in links:
        print(i.get_attribute('href'))
```

Now you have all the links.  With a simple for loop, you can proceed.

Enjoy!