# How do I get the irish price values in euro when web scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping

When executing the python code below I get a list of values in pounds(£) from the UK website. How do I get the list of prices from the irish(IE) website. Cheers.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


price = []

def asos(soup_in):
    # price
    price_div = soup_in.find_all( class_='qU9n4CQ')


    for container in price_div:
        container = container.text
        print(container) # Displays Pounds(£)

url = "https://www.asos.com/men/t-shirts-vests/cat/?cid=7616&nlid=mw|clothing|shop+by+product|t-shirts+%26+vests"
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:86.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0"}
results = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")
asos(soup)


asos_t_shirt = pd.DataFrame({
    'Prices': price

})
```

when I am on the link - [https://www.asos.com/men/t-shirts-vests/cat/?cid=7616&nlid=mw|clothing|shop+by+product|t-shirts+%26+vests](https://www.asos.com/men/t-shirts-vests/cat/?cid=7616&nlid=mw%7Cclothing%7Cshop+by+product%7Ct-shirts+%26+vests) it displays irish prices in euros but when I execute the code I receive values in pounds. Any help would be greatly appreciated

OUTPUT:

```
£10.00
£18.00
£18.00
£25.00
£22.00
£20.00
ETC...
```

Updated CODE

```
import requests

query = """query {
    data {
    product {
      name
    }
  }
}"""

url = 'https://www.zalando.ie/api/graphql/'
r = requests.post(url, json={'query': query})
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: When researching in preparation for a web scrape, always do your research in Incognito mode. This will prevent previously selected settings from interfering, and will let you record every step of the way needed to scrap a website in the way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I viewed the page in my browser. Scrolling to the bottom of the page, there's a "Load More" button. I logged my browser's network traffic and pressed the "Load More" button, and saw that my browser made various XHR HTTP GET requests, one of which is to a REST API that returns JSON, containing all the product information you could ever want (including prices). This is not uncommon, as this is how many modern online stores are implemented. The product information is gathered via an API, and then the DOM is populated asynchronously using JavaScript. It's a bit strange though the products on the first "page" - the products which are immediately visible upon visiting the store - are baked directly into the HTML, rather than retrieved from an API. We can retrieve these products via the API too, though:

```
def get_products():
    import requests

    api_url = "https://www.asos.com/api/product/search/v2/categories/7616"

    params = {
        "channel": "desktop-web",
        "country": "GB",
        "currency": "GBP",
        "keyStoreDataversion": "hnm9sjt-28",
        "lang": "en-GB",
        "limit": "72",
        "offset": "0",
        "rowlength": "4",
        "store": "COM"
    }

    response = requests.get(api_url, params=params)
    response.raise_for_status()

    return response.json()["products"]
    

def main():

    products = get_products()

    print("Discovered {} product(s).".format(len(products)))

    for product in products:
        print("\"{}\" - ({})".format(product["name"], product["price"]["current"]["text"]))
    
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
Discovered 72 product(s).
"ASOS DESIGN oversized t-shirt with crew neck in navy" - (£10.00)
"ASOS DESIGN organic relaxed long sleeve t-shirt with colour block sleeves" - (£18.00)
"ASOS DESIGN long sleeve t-shirt with cut and sew panels in grey" - (£18.00)
"ASOS DESIGN 2 pack long sleeve sleeve waffle t-shirt" - (£25.00)
"ASOS DESIGN 5 pack t-shirt with crew neck" - (£26.00)
"Nike World Tour Pack graphic oversized t-shirt in black" - (£29.95)
"ASOS DESIGN organic muscle fit t-shirt with crew neck in black" - (£4.80)
"New Look t-shirt with crew neck in brown" - (£3.25)
"Vans Off The Wall Classic t-shirt in pink" - (£20.15)
"Original Penguin small logo t-shirt slim fit in black" - (£20.00)
"ASOS DESIGN knitted vest with floral design in khaki" - (£22.00)
"ASOS DESIGN oversized t-shirt in tie-dye organic cotton with smile chest print" - (£20.00)
...
```

The way it's written right now doesn't actually solve your currency problem - it's just a nicer way of getting the data (rather than scraping it with BeautifulSoup or Selenium). You would think that getting the prices in euros would be as simple as changing the `"currency"` key-value pair in the `params` query-string parameter dictionary, and it is (almost) that easy. Just changing the `"currency"` from `"GBP"` to `"EUR"` gives a `400` response, so that means our request wasn't formulated correctly. It turns out that this API doesn't like any discrepancies between the `"currency"`, `"country"`, `"lang"` and `"store"` key-value pairs. In other words, we have to change all four of these query-string parameters in order for the API to accept our request, and all four of them have to make sense.

For example, I changed the query-string parameters to the following, to make it look like we're shopping in the German store, so that we can get the prices in euros:

```
params = {
    "channel": "desktop-web",
    "country": "DE",
    "currency": "EUR",
    "keyStoreDataversion": "hnm9sjt-28",
    "lang": "de-DE",
    "limit": "72",
    "offset": "0",
    "rowlength": "4",
    "store": "DE"
}
```

Running the script again with the applied change, we get the following output:

```
Discovered 72 product(s).
"ASOS DESIGN – Langärmliges Shirt mit Einsätzen im Patchwork-Design in Grau" - (22,99 €)
"ASOS DESIGN – 2er-Pack langärmlige Shirts mit Waffelstruktur" - (31,99 €)
"ASOS Daysocial – Oversized T-Shirt in Blau mit akzentuiertem Batikmuster" - (24,99 €)
"ASOS DESIGN – Strick-Trägershirt im Blumendesign in Khaki" - (27,99 €)
"ASOS DESIGN – Oversize-T-Shirt aus Bio-Baumwolle mit Batikmuster und Smiley-Print auf der Brust" - (25,99 €)
"ASOS Daysocial – Oversize-T-Shirt mit Blumen- und Logoprints auf der Vorder- und Rückseite in Grün, Kombiteil" - (22,99 €)
"ASOS Daysocial – Oversize-T-Shirt mit mehreren bunten Sonnen- und Logoprints in Blaugrün" - (24,99 €)
"ASOS Daysocial – Oversize-T-Shirt mit lila und blauem Batikmuster" - (22,99 €)
"Reclaimed Vintage – Inspired – Überfärbtes Oversize-T-Shirt in Anthrazit" - (28,99 €)
"Reclaimed Vintage – Inspired – Verwaschenes Oversized-T-Shirt mit Logo" - (28,99 €)
"ASOS DESIGN – Oversize-T-Shirt in gebrochenem Weiß mit „Paris”-Cityprint" - (14,99 €)
...
```

As you can see, the prices are in euros now (good), but the product names have changed into their corresponding German versions (not good). I guess the real solution would involve making two requests to the API - one with English query-string parameters (to collect product names), and one with German query-string parameters (for price information in euros). It's also important to notice that the order in which the products appear in the first (English) request is not the same order in which they appear in the second (German) request. I think this issue could be solved by looking at every retrieved product's ID, matching names and prices from both requests by their product ID.

---

EDIT - Just wrote a script that collects all English and German products. In total there are 8993 English products, and 8755 German products. Between the two sets of products, 6552 share the same product ID. This means that, not only do the two stores have different amounts of products, both stores also have products which are unique to them. So, it seems that there are 6552 products for which you could theoretically get an English name and an associated German price.

---

EDIT - It makes a lot of sense to just get the Irish products, since you get the English product names and price information in euros.

For each request that we make to the API, we can request information for at most 200 products at a time (this limit seems to be set by the API). Below you'll find the updated code. `get_products` is now a generator that yields lists of 200 products at a time. We accumulate all these product-lists in one giant list in the `main` function. We use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` to "unpack" the lists, so that we're left with one giant list of products, rather than a list of lists:

```
def get_products():
    import requests
    import itertools

    api_url = "https://www.asos.com/api/product/search/v2/categories/7616"

    limit = 200

    params = {
        "channel": "desktop-web",
        "country": "IE",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "keyStoreDataversion": "hnm9sjt-28",
        "lang": "en-GB",
        "limit": str(limit),
        "rowlength": "4",
        "store": "ROE"
    }

    count = itertools.count(0, step=limit)

    for offset in map(str, count):
        params["offset"] = offset
        response = requests.get(api_url, params=params)
        response.raise_for_status()

        products = response.json()["products"]
        print("Getting next {} products...".format(len(products)))
        if len(products) != limit:
            yield products
            break
        yield products

def main():

    from itertools import chain

    print("Retrieving IE products.\n")

    products = list(chain.from_iterable(get_products()))

    print("Discovered {} product(s) in total.\n".format(len(products)))

    for product in products:
        print("\"{}\" - ({})".format(product["name"], product["price"]["current"]["text"]))

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
Retrieving IE products.

Getting next 200 products...
Getting next 200 products...
Getting next 200 products...
Getting next 200 products...
...
Getting next 200 products...
Getting next 200 products...
Getting next 200 products...
Getting next 152 products...
Discovered 8752 product(s) in total.

"ASOS DESIGN organic relaxed long sleeve t-shirt with colour block sleeves" - (€22.99)
"ASOS DESIGN long sleeve t-shirt with cut and sew panels in grey" - (€22.99)
"ASOS DESIGN 2 pack long sleeve sleeve waffle t-shirt" - (€31.99)
"ASOS DESIGN knitted vest with floral design in khaki" - (€27.99)
"ASOS DESIGN oversized t-shirt in tie-dye organic cotton with smile chest print" - (€25.99)
"ASOS Daysocial oversized t-shirt with placement tie dye in blue" - (€24.99)
"ASOS Daysocial co-ord oversized t-shirt with front and back flower logo prints in green" - (€22.99)
"ASOS Daysocial oversized t-shirt with multi placement sun and logo prints in teal" - (€24.99)
"COLLUSION oversized long sleeve t-shirt with print in acid wash pique fabric" - (€20.99)
...
```

Comment: M Thank you for your efforts. Don't suppose you would be able to change the "params" to the Irish version of the site(IE) and get it to work.

Comment: m I have found the soultion to the parameters -  params = {
        "channel": "desktop-web",
        "country": "IE",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "keyStoreDataversion": "hnm9sjt-28",
        "lang": "en-GB",
        "limit": "72",
        "offset": "0",
        "rowlength": "4",
        "store": "ROE"
    }

Comment: Where did you find the https://www.asos.com/api/product/search/v2/categories/7616 for tshirts?

Comment: @jeffgrills Sorry, I forgot that you wanted Irish price information specifically. [Take a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65585597/how-to-click-a-link-by-text-with-no-text-in-python/65585861#65585861) I posted to someone else's webscraping question, in which I go more in depth about how to find the API URL. I suppose changing to the Irish params gives you the best of both worlds - the product names in English, and prices in euros.

Comment: Cheers. I will look into this

Comment: Do you have the code of how to extract all the tshirts?

Comment: @jeffgrills Sure, I've edited my answer and included the updated code at the end of my post. If this answer helped you, consider upvoting/marking my answer as the "accepted answer" :).

Comment: I have added a piece of code for zalando following the same steps as Asos but does not seem to run. I think there is a small error somewhere. Do you know where the error is? I get a json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) error

Comment: `JSONDecodeError` means that the JSON could not be parsed because it is ill-formed. Where did you get the API URL `www.zalando.ie/api/catalog/articles` from? In my network traffic I see requests being made to a GraphQL API with a different looking endpoint.

Comment: I cleared the browsing history and now I see https://www.zalando.ie/api/graphql/. Im trying to do what I did for asos but with graphql. Im getting a 403 error. Im it possible to access this data? Do you know the steps?(code updated above)

Comment: @jeffgrills I played around with it, but this API is quite complicated. Not all APIs will be the same. GraphQL is not the same as REST - there's only one endpoint, and you have to send an HTTP POST with a query payload. The query has to be formulated exactly right in order for the API to accept it. I tried my best, but wasn't able to fully mimic the requests the browser makes.