# Getting a 403 error on a webscraping script

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, user-agent

I have a web scraping script that has recently ran into a 403 error.
It worked for a while with just the basic code but now has been running into 403 errors.
I've tried using user agents to circumvent this and it very briefly worked, but those are now getting a 403 error too.

**Does anyone have any idea how to get this script running again?**

If it helps, here is some context:
The purpose of the script is to find out which artists are on which Tidal playlists, for the purpose of this question - I have only included the snippet of code that gets the site as that is where the error occurs.

Thanks in advance!

The basic code looks like this:

```python
baseurl = 'https://tidal.com/browse'
for i in platformlist:
  url = baseurl+str(i[0])
  tidal = requests.get(url)
    tidal.raise_for_status()
    if tidal.status_code != 200:
      print ("Website Error: ", url)
      pass
    else:
      soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(tidal.text,"lxml")
      text = str(soup)
      text2 = text.lower()
```

With user-agents:

```html
user_agent_list = [
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.1 Safari/605.1.15',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36',
]

url = 'https://tidal.com/playlist/1b418bb8-90a7-4f87-901d-707993838346'

for i in range(1,4):
    #Pick a random user agent
    user_agent = random.choice(user_agent_list)
    #Set the headers 
    headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
    #Make the request
    tidal = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    
    print("Request #%d\nUser-Agent Sent:%s\n\nHeaders Received by HTTPBin:"%(i,user_agent))
    print(tidal.status_code)
    print("-------------------")

#tidal = requests.get(webpage)
tidal.raise_for_status()
print(tidal.status_code)

#make webpage content legible
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(tidal.text,"lxml")
print(soup)

#turn bs4 type content into text
text = str(soup)
text2 = text.lower()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to suggest an alternative solution - one that doesn't involve BeautifulSoup.

I visited the main page and clicked on an album, while at the same time logging my network traffic. I noticed that my browser made an HTTP POST request to a GraphQL API, which accepts a custom query string as part of the POST payload which dictates the format of the response data. The response is JSON, and it contains all the information we requested with the original query string (in this case, all artists for every track of a playlist). Normally this API is used by the page to populate itself asynchronously using JavaScript, which is what normally happens when the page is viewed in a browser like it's meant to be.
Since we have the API endpoint, request headers and POST payload, we can imitate that request in Python to get a JSON response:

```
def main():

    import requests

    url = "https://tidal.com/browse/api"

    headers = {
        "accept": "application/json",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0"
    }

    query = """
    query ($playlistId: String!) {
        playlist(uuid: $playlistId) {
            creator {
                name
            }
            title
            tracks {
                albumID
                albumTitle
                artists {
                    id
                    name
                }
                id
                title
            }
        }
    }
    """

    payload = {
        "operationName": None,
        "query": query,
        "variables": {
            "playlistId": "1b418bb8-90a7-4f87-901d-707993838346"
        }
    }

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)
    response.raise_for_status()

    playlist = response.json()["data"]["playlist"]

    print("Artists in playlist \"{}\":".format(playlist["title"]))
    for track_number, track in enumerate(playlist["tracks"], start=1):
        artists = ", ".join(artist["name"] for artist in track["artists"])
        print("Track #{} [{}]: {}".format(track_number, track["title"], artists))

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
Artists in playlist "New Arrivals":
Track #1 [Higher Power]: Coldplay
Track #2 [i n t e r l u d e]: J. Cole
Track #3 [Fast (Motion)]: Saweetie
Track #4 [Miss The Rage]: Trippie Redd, Playboi Carti
Track #5 [In My Feelings (feat. Quavo & Young Dolph)]: Tee Grizzley, Quavo, Young Dolph
Track #6 [Thumbin]: Kash Doll
Track #7 [Tiempo]: Ozuna
...
```

You can change the `playlistId` key-value pair in the `payload` dictionary to get the artist information for any playlist.

Take a look at [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65585597/how-to-click-a-link-by-text-with-no-text-in-python/65585861#65585861) I posted, where I go more in-depth on how to log your network traffic, finding API endpoints and imitating requests.

Comment: Thanks so much! 
I was not aware they even had an API - and it does work so that's amazing :)