# I'm trying to scrape QS world university rankings with Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract university names, ranks and academic reputation from the QS ranking website. (address below) 'Academic reputation' data is in the tab 'Rankings Indicators'.

"https://www.topuniversities.com/university-rankings/world-university-rankings/2022"

First I tried to get university names with Python, which was unsuccessful. This code seems to give a lot of 'a' tag data, but I could not get university names with the class "uni-link".

Could anybody please help me to improve my code?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url="https://www.topuniversities.com/university-rankings/world-university-rankings/2022"
response=requests.get(url)

html = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

uni= soup.find_all('a', class_="uni-link")
for item in uni:
    print(item.text)
```

Comment: Have you LOOKED at the code for that web site?  The HTML you fetch doesn't contain any of the university data.  The web site is all built dynamically using Javascript.  You will have to use something like Selenium to run a browser to get the Javascript interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim Roberts has pointed out, the actual HTML document of the page from which you're trying to scrape is just an empty template. The DOM is populated asynchronously at a later point in time using JavaScript. In this case, when clicking on the `Rankings Indicator` tab, JavaScript makes an XHR HTTP GET request to an API, the response of which is JSON and contains the information you're looking for. You just have to imitate that request.

Some parts of the JSON, in this case, happen to contain HTML, which you can parse with BeautifulSoup.

```
def get_entries():
    import requests

    url = "https://www.topuniversities.com/sites/default/files/qs-rankings-data/en/3740566_indicators.txt?1637817445?v=1637823042256"

    headers = {
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
        "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"
    }

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    response.raise_for_status()

    def make_pretty(entry):
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
        return {
            "name": Soup(entry["uni"], "html.parser").select_one(".uni-link").get_text(strip=True),
            "rank": entry["overall_rank"],
            "reputation": Soup(entry["ind_76"], "html.parser").select_one(".td-wrap-in").get_text(strip=True)
        }

    yield from map(make_pretty, response.json()["data"])

def main():

    from itertools import islice

    for entry in islice(get_entries(), 5):
        print(entry)
    
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
{'name': 'Massachusetts Institute of Technology (MIT)', 'rank': '1', 'reputation': '100'}
{'name': 'University of Oxford', 'rank': '2', 'reputation': '100'}
{'name': 'Stanford University', 'rank': '3', 'reputation': '100'}
{'name': 'University of Cambridge', 'rank': '4', 'reputation': '100'}
{'name': 'Harvard University', 'rank': '5', 'reputation': '100'}
```

In this example, I'm just printing the first five entries. To print all 1300 entries, simply change `main` to:

```
def main():

    for entry in get_entries():
        print(entry)
    
    return 0
```

Comment: Wow! I've been struggling with this for a week and you saved my life! Thank you so much Paul for sharing your brilliance and precious time to help me. I've regained my inner peace thanks to you!

Comment: @dolphin20 Happy to help! If you're curious, take a look at [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65585597/how-to-click-a-link-by-text-with-no-text-in-python/65585861#65585861) I posted to a similar question, where I go more in-depth about how to use your browser's dev tools to log your network traffic, discovering and imitating XHR requests, etc.