# Combine dictionary output of iterator function into single dictionary

Tags: python

I'm trying to web scrape the QS website (using code I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70106723/im-trying-to-scrape-qs-world-university-rankings-with-python)) and want to combine the output of the for loop below into a single dictionary, so that I can turn it into a dataframe using pandas.

I've tried pulling the data out as lists and using `.append` but no luck, and haven't been able to convert the dictionaries to a df as the return function only returns the last output.

Python code:

```
def get_entries():
    import requests
    #2023 Masters in Finance Ranking Indicators URL#
    url = "https://www.topuniversities.com//sites//default//files//qs-rankings-data//en//3827348_indicators.txt?rjbmn2"

    headers = {
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
        "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"
    }

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    response.raise_for_status()

    def Entries(entry):
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
        
        try: 
            return {
            "Name": Soup(entry["uni"], "html.parser").select_one(".uni-link").find(text=True, recursive=False).strip(),
            "Programme": Soup(entry["uni"], "html.parser").select_one(".uni-link").find("span").find(text=True, recursive=False),
            "Rank": entry["overall_rank"],
            "Overall Score": Soup(entry["overall"], "html.parser").select_one(".td-wrap-in").get_text(strip=True),
            "Value for Money": Soup(entry["ind_1"], "html.parser").select_one(".td-wrap-in").get_text(strip=True),
            "Thought Leadership": Soup(entry["ind_2"], "html.parser").select_one(".td-wrap-in").get_text(strip=True),
            "Employability": Soup(entry["ind_27"], "html.parser").select_one(".td-wrap-in").get_text(strip=True),
            "Diversity": Soup(entry["ind_29"], "html.parser").select_one(".td-wrap-in").get_text(strip=True),
            "Alumni Outcomes": Soup(entry["ind_33"], "html.parser").select_one(".td-wrap-in").get_text(strip=True)
        }
            
        except:
            return {
            "Name": Soup(entry["uni"], "html.parser").select_one(".uni-link").find(text=True, recursive=False).strip(),
            "Programme": Soup(entry["uni"], "html.parser").select_one(".uni-link").find("span"),
                #Finds span tags instead of text for instances where no programme#
            "Rank": entry["overall_rank"],
            "Overall Score": Soup(entry["overall"], "html.parser").select_one(".td-wrap-in").get_text(strip=True),
            "Value for Money": Soup(entry["ind_1"], "html.parser").select_one(".td-wrap-in").get_text(strip=True),
            "Thought Leadership": Soup(entry["ind_2"], "html.parser").select_one(".td-wrap-in").get_text(strip=True),
            "Employability": Soup(entry["ind_27"], "html.parser").select_one(".td-wrap-in").get_text(strip=True),
            "Diversity": Soup(entry["ind_29"], "html.parser").select_one(".td-wrap-in").get_text(strip=True),
            "Alumni Outcomes": Soup(entry["ind_33"], "html.parser").select_one(".td-wrap-in").get_text(strip=True)
        }
      
    yield from map(Entries, response.json()["data"])

def dicts():

    from itertools import islice
    
    for entry in get_entries():
        print(entry)
         
    return
```

Comment: Which `return` function only returns the last output? `Entries(...)` appears to return a long dictionary and `dicts()` returns `None` anyways.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Joey. If I print(dicts()) then it returns a long list of individual dictionaries from the for-loop, and then a final 'None' from the return. I've tried to combine these and turn them into a dataframe but when I try to assign dicts to a variable it only returns the 'None'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pandas.DataFrame` can read data from generators. For example:

```
def gen():
    from itertools import product, tee
    yield from [{'a': i, 'b': j} for i, j in product(*tee(range(3)))]

df = pd.DataFrame(gen())
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   a  b
0  0  0
1  0  1
2  0  2
3  1  0
4  1  1
5  1  2
6  2  0
7  2  1
8  2  2
```

So I think that the code you have can be simplified like:

```
def dicts():
    from pandas import DataFrame
    return DataFrame(get_entries())
```

Or just one line:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(get_entries())
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much Vitalizzare! I'm very new to python so still getting to grips with generators, but both of your solutions worked. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Not all of the entries in the returned JSON structure contain a 'uni' key. With the code as shown in the question, this will result in a AttributeError exception.

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly then you can build a "master" dictionary as a superset of all the dictionaries constructed by get_entries() which you can then pass to a DataFrame constructor.

This may help:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

def get_entries():
    def Entries(entry):
        try:
            uni_link = Soup(entry['uni'], 'lxml').select_one('.uni-link')
            return {
                'name': uni_link.find(text=True, recursive=False).strip(),
                "Programme": uni_link.find("span").find(text=True, recursive=False),
                "Rank": entry["overall_rank"],
                "Overall Score": Soup(entry["overall"], "lxml").select_one(".td-wrap-in").get_text(strip=True),
                "Value for Money": Soup(entry["ind_1"], "lxml").select_one(".td-wrap-in").get_text(strip=True),
                "Thought Leadership": Soup(entry["ind_2"], "lxml").select_one(".td-wrap-in").get_text(strip=True),
                "Employability": Soup(entry["ind_27"], "lxml").select_one(".td-wrap-in").get_text(strip=True),
                "Diversity": Soup(entry["ind_29"], "lxml").select_one(".td-wrap-in").get_text(strip=True),
                "Alumni Outcomes": Soup(entry["ind_33"], "lxml").select_one(".td-wrap-in").get_text(strip=True)
                }
        except AttributeError:
            return {}

    (r := requests.get('https://www.topuniversities.com/sites/default/files/qs-rankings-data/en/3827348_indicators.txt?rjbmn2')).raise_for_status()
    
    yield from map(Entries, r.json()['data'])

result = {}

for d in get_entries():
    for k, v in d.items():
        result.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

df = pd.DataFrame(result)

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                            name                        Programme Rank Overall Score Value for Money Thought Leadership Employability Diversity Alumni Outcomes
0                      HEC Paris  Master in International Finance    1          96.5             100               99.1          98.3      71.7             100
1                  Oxford (Said)          MSc Financial Economics    2          96.4            99.1               93.8           100      78.5             100
2         London Business School        MSc in Financial Analysis    3          95.1            96.1               93.5          99.4      73.5            99.9
3                    MIT (Sloan)                Master of Finance    4          94.4            96.6               94.1          97.2      70.9             100
4                UCLA (Anderson)  Master of Financial Engineering    5          91.5            96.1                 95          90.9      60.4             100
..                           ...                              ...  ...           ...             ...                ...           ...       ...             ...
161              Tulsa (Collins)                    MS in Finance  184                          52.1                 24          21.4      28.4            34.5
162             Universidad Esan                Master of Finance  186                          62.6               29.6          36.7      34.7              20
163  University of South Florida                    MS in Finance  189                          54.7               38.6          25.7      50.7            34.5
164           Vilnius University              Finance and Banking  190                            33               47.2            48      43.7            27.9
165                          hsc     Master of Science in Finance  192                          72.8               32.9          32.6        50            21.9
```

**Note:**

Code changed to use lxml as that's generally faster than the default html.parser

Comment: I think you may have some problems with the `result` as you suggest to construct this dictionary. Not in this very case, I guess, but in general if some keys are missed you can miss `nan` values and your lists will have different length, which will cause `ValueError` when passed to `pd.DataFrame`.

Comment: @Vitalizzare The answer was tested against actual values currently emitted from that URL. My answer is offered as a guide and not a definitive / robust solution. If I was writing this for myself it would look very different

Comment: Thanks @OldBill for your answer as well, I'll definitely explore your solution as an alternative method and look into the pros/cons of each. As I mentioned in my reply to Vitalizzare, I'm still very new to this and fully appreciate my code is probably....unusual....cheers