# Python Selenium - Get Link from Within a Class

Tags: python, html, selenium, href

I am attempting to scrape the `href` from the following HTML, but I need the second data class to identify the `href`:

```
<tr>
<td class="data">
    <a target="_new" title="Title" href="https://somesite.com/file_to_scrape.pdf">Scraped Class</a>
<br>
</td>
<td class="data">Text to Identify Above Link</td>
<td class="data">Not relevant text</td>
</tr>
```

The first thing I do is pull back a list of all classes that are named `data`:

```
ls_class = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("data")
```

but when I loop through:

```
for clas in ls_class:
   print(clas.text)
   print(clas.get_attribute('href'))
```

The print out is:

```
Scraped Class
None
Text to Identify Above Link
None
Not Relevant Text
None
```

How can I get the nested `href` when present in a `data` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work using a solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664253/selenium-how-to-get-the-content-of-href-within-some-targeted-class/19664702):

```
 ls_class = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class='data']")

 for clas in ls_class:
     print(clas.text)
     try:
         print(clas.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href'))
     except:
         print("No Link")
```

Now my output is:

```
Scraped Class
https://somesite.com/file_to_scrape.pdf
Text to Identify Above Link
No Link
Not Relevant Text
No Link
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getting

```
ls_class = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("data")
```

You can get directly

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class='data']//a")
for element in elements:
   print(element.text)
   print(element.get_attribute('href'))
```

**UPD**
I think you can get the desired element directly by this code:

```py
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[.//td[@class='data'][text()='Text to Identify Above Link']//td[@class='data']//a[@href]")
print(element.get_attribute('href'))
```

Comment: When I do this, it doesnt return the second class which has text I need to identify the prior link. I only get classes with `href`.

Comment: Moment, maybe I misunderstood you. is all you want is to get the `"https://somesite.com/file_to_scrape.pdf` value (this value is unknown, we have to get it) while this `a` element is inside some `td` element so that the next sibling of this `td` is `td` with known text `Text to Identify Above Link`? Correct?

Comment: Yes, I need to get both the `href` from the first class and the text from the second class of `Text to Identify Above Link`, otherwise I dont know what the link is for. I tried `find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class='data']")` but that just gets me the same output as what I originally had.

Comment: In the example HTML you provided the second `td` with the `Text to Identify Above Link` text has no `a` with `href` inside it.

Comment: Because there is no `href` in the second `data` class. I need to get the first and second `data` class consecutively in a list of elements and then when I have identified the link from the text in the second `data` class, I want to extract the `href` from the first `data` class, if that makes sense.

Comment: Ok, but there are only 2 `td` elements with class=data , the second one is with the identifier text and the first one is with the href we need to extract. Yes?

Comment: Well there are multiple elements on the actual page with `class=data`, but the identifying `data` class will always be directly after the `href` data class.

Comment: Ok, these 2 `td`s are inside some parent element. There is no more `td`s with class name `data` inside that parent element?

Comment: If so, what is that parent element tag name? `tr`?

Comment: I expanded the HTML in my question, yes it is bounded by `tr`, but no there are actually 4 elements of class name `data`, but only the first and second are relevant to me.

Comment: I hope the updated answer will work correctly

Comment: please let me know if now this is what you looked for

Comment: Actually I ended up figuring out the answer from another thread which I posted. Thanks for the help though.  When I tried your updated code snippet I received a `is not a valid XPath expression` error